# Where the listview stores the image in android when downloaded from server

Tags: android, android-listview, android-sdcard

### I have an app that downloaded the data from server(images) and lists those images in listview of android application

---

When we add an image(downloaded from server) to the listview where the listview stores the image
I mean in which location listview stores

- Shared preferences ?
- internal storage ?
- Others ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is stored in the Internal Storage.
You can check it by clicking DDMS>File Explorer>data>data>App_package_name 
and there you go.

Sometimes it might not display when you click DDMS, then you just have to close and re-start the eclipse again. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You add you code that will identify where you store images.
Generaly in Data/data/YourPackage/

Answer (score 1):

`ListView` doesn't stores anything itself - it's just a container you use to represent some data in form of list. All views you put in `ListView` stores in device memory - including images.

Answer (score 1):

They are in the application package cache memory.

i.e data/data/YourPackage/